# In Python "requests" module, how do I check whether the server is down or 500?

Tags: python, rest, http

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
print str(r.status_code)
```

I want to check if my server is both **down** or a internal 500 error.

How can I check both using requests?

Comment: Well, either your server answers, in this case it's not really down and your above code will work (just add an if stauts == 500 check), or it won't answer and then the request will fail and throw an exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Requests throws different types of exceptions depending on what's causing your request to fail.

```
import requests.exceptions

try:
    r = requests.get('http://example.com')
    r.raise_for_status()  # Raises a HTTPError if the status is 4xx, 5xxx
except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout):
    print "Down"
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print "4xx, 5xx"
else:
    print "All good!"  # Proceed to do stuff with `r`
```

Comment: I'd only like one exception instead of two. Ca I delete the "requests.exceptions" part and just have except?

Comment: If you want to catch two exceptions with one block, use a tuple: `except (exception1, exception2, exception3, etcetc)`. (This is a tuple because in Python 2 `except exception1, exception2` means something else.

Comment: What if I dont want to use `r.raise_for_status()` (perhaps a policy of raising internal exceptions) ? There must be a way to handle using the `status_code`

Comment: @MrMesees The status code at in the `r.status_code`, so if you don't want requests to raise an exception, then write your own code to look at the status.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasOrozco I did check. The code I used was heavily influenced by the internals of the request framework. I used `elif 400 <= response.status_code < 500:` inside a custom handler to bubble library specific exceptions, hiding the implementation detail of requests lib